# Why doesn't Eclipse find parse from pattern.de package but pattern.de.Twitter however?

Tags: python, eclipse

I don't know what is wront. I installed `pattern` with `pip install pattern` which is not located under `/use/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. I also included it in `Libraries` under `Prefences > Interpreters > Python Interpreter`

For some reason it can find

```
from pattern.web import Twitter
```

but it does **not** find

```
from pattern.de import parse
```

What am I missing here?

I tried to remove and re-add the interpreter in the Eclipse settings, I closed and re-opened the project and I also restarted Eclipse. Nothing is working.

And additionally: Using `pattern.de` from the Terminal runs flawless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they changed the package but not the documentation.

```
from pattern.text.de import parse
```

---

[image]